# auto zoom and auto center to show all markers in window

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps to show locations using markers. I am passing an array of locations to initialize(). I want to set auto zoom and auto center to map such that all markers are visible. The map should take zoom value such that all markers can be seen at once.  .this is my code:

```
     function initialize(arr) { 
      var myOptions = {
        zoom:13,
        center: arr[0],
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
      route = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: arr,
            map:map
          });

              i=0;
              interval = setInterval(function() { 

                if(i<=arr.length)
                    {

                     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: arr[i],
                        map: map 

                      });
                     i++;

                    }//if

                else if(i>arr.length){

              window.clearInterval(interval);   
                }//else if
              },1000);//interval

}  //initialize
```

I have below code for this, but not getting how and where to use it.

```
         var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
                latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latlngbounds));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it seems your using multiple markers and you want to set zoom level.

If so my suggestion is to take a look at [**`fitBounds()`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

> ***fitBounds()*** method adjusts the map's viewport in order to view the
>   passed LatLngBounds in full at the centre of the map.

Check out this sample [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/22qte/) for demo.